# How to send a HTTP error for a Java RESTful web service?

Tags: java, web-services, http, error-handling

I have done this [tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/) and now I want to throw an error from this webservice, like HTTP error code `403` or `400`.

How can i do this? I noticed that i have an interface of type `HttpServletResponse`, but I don't know how I can use it. Do I have to import something else?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException;

import sun.awt.RequestFocusController;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton;
import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Request;
import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
@GET
public Response check(@QueryParam("username") String username) {
   if (facade.checkUser(username)) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
   }
   return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: and if i want to return a string or an int or one of this codes?

Comment: Set the entity of the response.  Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("HELLO").build()

Comment: Sorry about this, but I've downloaded the sources on the Tutorial link, been looking at this entry, and I cant figure what **Response**  object you are using here.  
This `import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response;` doesn't have the status() method. Can you please help me here figure out what you two have seen that eluded me