# how to receive parameters with a PUT method in java web service

Tags: java, jax-rs, put

So I have asked this question [with the return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353307/how-to-send-http-error-for-a-java-restful-web-service) .

Now i try to make a `PUT` method like this:

```
@PUT
@Path("deleteAbsence")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response deleteAbsence(@QueryParam("id") String absenceID) {
  String data = null;
  return Response.ok("asda {"+absenceID+"}").build();
}
```

And my `absenceID` is `null`. What do I have to change to receive the parameter?

here is the answer i receive from the server with error 415:
[response](http://www.picz.ro/show-image.php?id=9775b75f17c4ac35edec7389588ca1cd)

Comment: Btw, if you are deleting a resource, why do you use PUT instead of DELETE?

Comment: It's not about calling the other method. It's about the API and what this API does. If it deletes a resource, you should probably use DELETE, if it updates a resource, you should probably use PUT. If you have a spare time, read http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.com/2012/04/rest-best-practices-using-http-verbs.html

Comment: When you define urls avoid verbs in your url as practice else you might endup with urls corresponding to each and every action. You will probably get stuck in between if you donot use things the expected way.

Answer (score 2):

Send the PUT request to `http://example.com/deleteAbsence/?id=42`

Comment: 405 Is not a query parameter error. It means that PUT method for the given url doesn't exist. Either you didn't register your resource, or you using the wrong url.

Comment: Btw, it cannot happen that absenceID, if you receive 405. You must not reach the method at all.

Comment: i also receive http status 415

Comment: 415 means unsupported media type. The @Consumes annotation doesn't match the Content-type header. (If DELETE was used, it would be irrelevant, but PUT may have a body)

Comment: Would you mind to update your question? What exactly you do and what you receive. Null, 405 and 415 are completely different flows.

Answer (score 1):

Call the Resource with the proper query parameter:

```
PUT http://example.com/deleteAbsence/?id=42
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. You are messing the query and path parameters.

Comment: it would be like this if i use GET like in the example, but i'm using PUT so it's something else... can't figured out what

Comment: @user1103707 Why do you think path parameters are for GET requests only? What is you question?

Comment: my question is how to receive parameters with PUT

Comment: In JAX-RS ALL the parameters (path, query and even matrix) are ALWAYS parsed in the same way. There is no difference, if you use GET, PUT, POST, DELETE or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

in the content i had to put:

```
   "<"absenceIDString >2 "<"/absenceIDString>
```

and the method looks like this:

```
@Consumes("application/xml")
@PUT
@Path("deleteAbsence")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response deleteAbsence( String absenceIDString) {
    String data = null;
    return Response.ok("asda {"+absenceIDString+"}").build();
   }
```

Comment: So you moved the id to the body and added @Consumes to fix the 415. Not very RESTful way.

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with your **Rest Web Service Explorer** configuration in MyEclipse. The screenshot shows your variable name as `absenseIdString` while it should be `id`. Make sure that you have configured the **Param Type** as `QueryParam`. In myeclispe config screen, default value is PathParam.

Check this [tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-10.html)